# Automatic Sales Tax Tables

Tags: e-commerce, shopping-cart, sales-tax

A client needs the ability for their shopping cart to automatically retrieve and keep up to date sales tax tables for at least the US, and preferably all countries with which the US has tax treaties. Is this a reasonable requirement? Hosted solutions are fine.

Answer (score 7):

One option may be to not collect sales tax at all.  Online retailers like Amazon and NewEgg don't.  Of course, check first with an accountant and/or tax lawyer to see if that's legal.

I strongly recommend against building your own sales tax system.  The complexities are enormous:

- In the U.S., sales taxes are handled
  by almost every government
  jurisdiction.  To build a database of
  sales tax data, you would have to
  know the applicable laws for every
  state, some counties and cities, and
  "special" taxing districts established for things like
  libraries, sports stadiums and public transportation
  systems.
- You would have to update this
  database on a daily basis, since any
  one of those jurisdictions can enact,
  modify or repeal taxing regulations
  at any time.
- You would have to figure out the
  "triangulation" rules for all of those
  jurisdictions.  Say I live in Arizona
  and purchase something online from
  Colorado.  I have the item shipped
  from Colorado to Texas.  Which
  jurisdiction gets the sales tax?  The
  answer depends on the tax laws of all
  three states, which may contradict
  one another.
- If you collect sales tax for a given
  jurisdiction and remit it to them,
  you can be subject to a tax audit by
  that jurisdiction.  Given all of the
  complexities listed above, if you
  built your own sales tax database,
  would you trust it in the context of
  a tax audit?

I recently worked with a client that purchased both the [iVAT](http://vatat.com/) (for Europe) and [Vertex](http://www.vertexinc.com/) (for U.S.) sales tax systems.  Integrating them into my client's products  emphasized how complex the whole process is, and how nice it is to have a third-party do the work for you.  Europe's various VAT tax systems are simple compared to the U.S. system.  In the U.S., many locations have more than one applicable sales tax.  There are some places in California that have five!

In short, don't collect tax if you don't absolutely have to.  Otherwise, buy - don't build.

Comment: +1 for the mind-numbing panic inducing thought of having to deal with conflicting taxes rules from multiple geographic locations and multiple government levels. i never thought of all that.

Answer (score 0):

I sure it is of use to the client. That's wat matters in this case.

You should have a separate table for the tax with a link to the transaction that generated it. The transaction table will also be able to help you get to the country where this transaction occured.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it a "reasonable" requirement, but it's do-able.  Find the appropriate government site(s) or sites consolidating them and write some screen-scraping code. Poll the sites, say, hourly for changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are large amounts of dollars being made on keeping databases up-to-date with US sales and use tax for on-line retailers, mobile phone companies, etc. There are subscription services as well (I wrote some of the products a few years back for one of the larger companies). They offered bi-monthy, monthly, quarterly, semi-annual, and annual updates (at rates compatible with the frequency, of course).

One such place to check is [here](http://www.salestax.com). I have no idea what their current fees are like, though.